# how to add document to firestore database using react native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

We are trying add documents values manually using react native app to firestore DB.

Here is the reference code we found for web

```
db.collection("cities").doc("LA").set({
    name: "Los Angeles",
    state: "CA",
    country: "USA"
})
.then(function() {
    console.log("Document successfully written!");
})
.catch(function(error) {
    console.error("Error writing document: ", error);
});
```

For react native we used this code

```
firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc("hello").add({
        title: this.state.textInput,
        complete: false,
      })
```

I'm getting error like add us not defined

How to add documents and collections to it ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here I found the solution for my data structure

```
firebase
  .firestore()
  .collection("Users")
  .doc("mydoc")
  .collection("Activities")
  .doc("Database")
  .set({
    key: "1",
    value: "",
  })
  .then((ref) => { console.log(ref) });
```

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing, but I want to set the uid of the document instead of Firebase auto generating one, anyone know how?

Answer (score 7):

You can add a document to a collection. You cannot add a document to a document.

To add a document to your `users` collection:

```
firebase.firestore().collection('users').add({
  title: this.state.textInput,
  complete: false,
})
```

So remove the `.doc("hello")` from there.

Comment: we have structure in such a way that, under collection we have documents and then collections

Comment: OK, so in that case you have a sub-collection under your document and need to identify the subcollection: `firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc("hello").collection("SUBCOLLECTION").add({`